# What happens with $f^{-1}(-f(x))$?

Tags: functions

I know that the composition of a function and its inverse $f^{-1}(f(x))$ always yields $x$, but what about $f^{-1}(-f(x))$? Or $f^{-1}(f(-x))$? Or $f^{-1}(-f(-x))$? I have tested the first option and I seem to get different answers for all tests. 

For example, with $f(x)=x^3$ I get $-x$.

For $f(x)=x^2$ I get $|x|i$.

For $f(x)=e^x$ I get $x+i \pi$.
Is there a general answer?

Comment: Apart from the fact that $f^{-1}(f(-x))=-x$, not much can be said in general. If you have some knowledge of a specific relationship between $f^{-1}(y)$ and $f^{-1}(-y)$, then that can be leveraged for the other cases.

Comment: Off the top of my head, it seems as if you can only get a general answer for the categories of even and odd, invertible functions.  What @Arthur says is the conclusion you get for invertible odd functions $f$.

Comment: There's no particular relation between f(-x) and f(x) so there needn't be any between f^-1(-f(x)).

Answer (score 1):

For an odd function,

$$f^{-1}(-f(x))=f^{-1}(f(-x))=-x.$$

For general functions, there is no particular relation. Anyway, the resulting function is always its own inverse,

$$g(x):=f^{-1}(-f(x))\implies g(g(x))=x.$$